# XAML and MySQL database access

Tags: c#, mysql, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I want to deploy an UWP application(VS 2015)on Raspberry Pi2.I have  a MySQL server running on another machine . Is it possible to execute the queries such as update,create,delete,add from the raspberry Pi(.xaml UWP) to the remote server on the same network.

Answer (score 0):

Its totally possible.

One option is building REST service on the remote server, and access it from Pi2 using http request.

Or you can make use of Socket API in UWP.